# Are there a automated method to solve problems in number theory like "the area method" in geometry?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Are there a automated method for number Theory,a method that find all integers solution, proof theorems, and solve number theory problems in general especially IMO PROBLEMS?

Comment: A short and exhaustive answer: no. Otherwise, there would be no challenge in solving such problems. Would you be interested in solving problems automatically like a computer? I wouldn't enjoy something automatical.

Comment: The brutal approach of trying trying every possibility is automated and works when you can prove the that the number of possible candidates is finite.

Comment: Not just that the number of candidates is finite, but you know how to enumerate that finite set.

Comment: But China has a method in the IMO

Comment: That solve number theory problems

Answer (score 2):

No.  In particular, Matiyasevich's negative answer to [Hilbert's 10th problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert's_tenth_problem) says there is no algorithm to decide whether a diophantine equation has solutions.

Comment: No.  Even for the apparently narrower Halting Problem, the absence of a solution has been proven.

Comment: but Chinese solves perfectly the number theory problems of the IMO, there is a method

Comment: @avs I don't see why you think the Halting Problem is "apparently narrower".  It's clear that an algorithm for the Halting problem would provide an algorithm for diophantine equations: just consider a Turing machine that searches the $n$-tuples of natural numbers and halts if it finds a solution of the Diophantine equation.  It's not at all obvious that an algorithm for Diophantine equations would let you solve the Halting Problem.